# How can the ecliptic be shown in Google Sky?

Tags: google-earth

How can the [ecliptic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecliptic) be shown in [Google Sky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Sky) (part of the [Google Earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Earth) application)?

Is it possible in v5.0 (I am using 5.0.11733.9347 for Windows) or in a later version?

[Google Groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Groups) question *[This application needs the ECLIPTIC](https://groups.google.com/group/google-sky-map/browse_thread/thread/b2c82133646a49c1)* seems to indicate it is not possbible whereas *[Using Google Earth's Sky feature in your classroom](http://www.google.com/educators/skyideas.html)* says "Use the Constellations layer to examine the concept of the ecliptic" (this is not very clear and does not explain how). I have turned on the Constellation layer, but the ecliptic does not show. It should be a line from the upper left, through the center and to the lower right of this view:

[image]

Perhaps it is possible. From *[Google Sky: hands on, plus Top 10 uncommonly cool sights](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=6884&p=98379)*:

> Yes, the bright curve is indeed the galactic plane and the fainter one the ecliptic.

But how?

Comment: None of those links seem to really point at the actual ecliptic in Google Earth, just google.com/sky and a suggestion of how to examine where it might be in Google Earth.  You might try asking this on astronomy.stackexchange.com.  You might also checkout Celestia http://www.shatters.net/celestia/download.html and Partiview http://www.haydenplanetarium.org/universe/partiview for sky viewing.